# Join model creation test failing because it is missing related models, not sure why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Here is the test that is failing:

```
before(:each) do
    @attr = { 
      :user_id => "1", 
      :project_id => "1",
      :owner_type => "client"
    }
  end

  it "should create a new instance given valid attributes" do
     Ownership.create!(@attr)
   end
```

Here is the failure:

```
Failures:

  1) Ownership should create a new instance given valid attributes
     Failure/Error: Ownership.create!(@attr)
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: User can't be blank, Project can't be blank
     # ./spec/models/ownership_spec.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I don't have any validation for a User or Project to not be blank. Here is my ownership model:

```
class Ownership < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :owner_type

  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user

  validates :user_id, :presence => true

  validates :project_id, :presence => true

  validates :owner_type, :presence => true

end
```

Am I missing something? What did I do wrong? Also, the ownerships aren't getting created in the actual app..this is what i'm using but isn't working:

```
current_user.ownerships.create(:owner_type => 'designer', :project => @project)
```

here is my user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :admin, :projects

  has_many :ownerships
  has_many :projects, :through => :ownerships

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :projects
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `:user_id` and `:project_id` to `attr_accesible`. Like you have done it for `:owner_type`. So it should look like

```
attr_accessible :owner_type, :user_id, :project_id
```

This should solve the problem.

Comment: that worked but the ownership isn't being created properly in the actual app. I added some more info in the original question.

Comment: Anything you want to assign as attributes, even the relationships, need to be under attr_accessible. Like :project, :user etc.

Comment: check out my ownership model...i do have it in the attr_accessible..but setting it through the method I listed in my question doesnt work.

Comment: oh wait...so you're saying I need :user and :project in my attr_accessible of my ownership model? but...it works when I do user.projects << project the only problem is that this doesn't allow me to set a value for the assication that is created

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible the problem is being caused because you are passing strings instead of integers for the values of `user_id` and `project_id`?

Comment: No, I realize now that my ownerships aren't getting created at all now, no idea why. Here is what I'm using to create a new ownership between a user and a project: current_user.ownerships.create(:owner_type => 'designer', :project => @project)