# How to << a Join Model with attributes to a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a User model which joins to another User model through a UserRelationship join table.  UserRelationships have an attribute (approved/pending/revoked) which must be set, but does not default to any option.  There are two associations which reflect this, traveler and delegate, so my models look like this:

```
User.rb
  has_many :traveler_relationships, :class_name => 'UserRelationship', :foreign_key => :delegate_id  
  has_many :travelers, :class_name => 'User', :through => :traveler_relationships

  has_many :delegate_relationships, :class_name => 'UserRelationship', :foreign_key => :user_id
  has_many :delegates, :class_name => 'User', :through => :delegate_relationships

  has_many :buddy_relationships, class_name: 'UserRelationship', foreign_key: :user_id
  has_many :buddies, class_name: 'User', through: :buddy_relationships, source: :delegate


UserRelationship.rb
  belongs_to :relationship_status
  belongs_to :traveler, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'user_id'
  belongs_to :delegate, :class_name => 'User'

  PENDING = 1
  CONFIRMED = 3
  REVOKED = 5
```

I'm trying to write up some specs where one user is related to another and the simplest way to write it would be `@user1.travelers << @user2` but this fails the database constraint that UserRelationship.relationship_status not be `null`.

When I try `@user1.buddies.create(delegate: @user2, relationship_status: RelationshipStatus::CONFIRMED)`, it fails saying `UnknownAttributeError` on `delegate`.  I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801839/join-model-creation-test-failing-because-it-is-missing-related-models-not-sure) and tried its solution, using attr_acessible, but it didn't change the `UnknownAttributeError`.

**What is the way to create this join record with an attribute set?**

Comment: How are users connected to their buddies? I see travelers and delegates, but no mention of buddies in the model declaration.

Comment: @Sharagoz Sorry, buddies was a synonym for delegates which I forgot to include here.  See my latest edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `UserRelationship` has a foreign_key `delegate_id` for the delegate

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :traveler_relationships, :class_name => 'UserRelationship', :foreign_key => :user_id
  has_many :delegate_relationships, :class_name => 'UserRelationship', :foreign_key => :delegate_id

  has_many :travelers, :class_name => 'User', :through => :traveler_relationships
  has_many :delegates, :class_name => 'User', :through => :delegate_relationships
end

class UserRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :traveler, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => :user_id
  belongs_to :delegate, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => :delegate_id

  PENDING = 1
  CONFIRMED = 3
  REVOKED = 5
end
```

I dont think you can use the shortcut `@user1.delegates << @user2` since you need to specify relationship status. Try:

```
@user1.traveler_relationships.create(delegate: @user2, relationship_status: RelationshipStatus::CONFIRMED)
```

I've excluded the buddy synonym here. It's complex enough as is. When this works you can look into adding synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track when you try to create from `buddies` (I'm assuming that's your join model relation).  The problem is that your column name is `relationship_status` and you were passing `status` to `create`. Try this:

```
@user1.buddies.create(delegate: @user2, relationship_status: RelationshipStatus::CONFIRMED
```

Comment: that's a good catch and I'll fix it too, but I'm still getting `UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: delegate`